# Search Xpages based on date range

Tags: date, search, range, xpages

I need to develop a search functionality into one of my client xpages to return documents based on 2 date fields, document date creation and document date of conclusion.

I already have a query field And im using a session scope for a singelo filter, it works... Now, I just need to return document based on this date range. Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sorted view with &startkey and &untilkey see: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/